# Get MAC address from integer value

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

In db value for MAC address in number format, for my query I need value in real format that like `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`.

**Example**: for number `9817108886245`, real MAC address value must be `08:ED:B9:49:B2:E5`.

I wrote next query:

```
select regexp_replace(lpad(upper(trim(to_char(9817108886245,
    'xxxxxxxxxxxx'))), 12, '0'),
    '^([A-Z0-9]{2})([A-Z0-9]{2})([A-Z0-9]{2})([A-Z0-9]{2})([A-Z0-9]{2})([A-Z0-9]{2})$'
    , '\1:\2:\3:\4:\5:\6') as MAC
from dual;
```

It is possible to simplify my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this would be a *shorter* query string but not exactly *simpler*

```
select substr(regexp_replace(
    upper(to_char(9817108886245,'00xxxxxxxxxxxx')),'([A-F0-9]{2})',':\1'),6) as MAC
from dual;
```

Comment: Good idea to use a less strict regexp expresion, I don't think about this.